# How to get Best Estimator on GridSearchCV (Random Forest Classifier Scikit)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

I'm running GridSearch CV to optimize the parameters of a classifier in scikit. Once I'm done, I'd like to know which parameters were chosen as the best.

Whenever I do so I get a `AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'best_estimator_'`, and can't tell why, as it seems to be a legitimate attribute on the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html).

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

X = data[usable_columns]
y = data[target]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1,max_features= 'sqrt' ,n_estimators=50, oob_score = True) 

param_grid = {
    'n_estimators': [200, 700],
    'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2']
}

CV_rfc = GridSearchCV(estimator=rfc, param_grid=param_grid, cv= 5)

print '\n',CV_rfc.best_estimator_
```

Yields:

```
`AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'best_estimator_'
```

Comment: For your information, max_features 'auto' and 'sqrt' are the same. They both compute max_features=sqrt(n_features).

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You have to fit your data before you can get the best parameter combination.

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
# Build a classification task using 3 informative features
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,
                           n_features=10,
                           n_informative=3,
                           n_redundant=0,
                           n_repeated=0,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=0,
                           shuffle=False)


rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1,max_features= 'sqrt' ,n_estimators=50, oob_score = True) 

param_grid = { 
    'n_estimators': [200, 700],
    'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2']
}

CV_rfc = GridSearchCV(estimator=rfc, param_grid=param_grid, cv= 5)
CV_rfc.fit(X, y)
print CV_rfc.best_params_
```

Comment: It worked indeed, thank you! Any idea as to why? (I thought gridSearch would find the parameters, but I couldn't even get the parameters back before fitting)

Comment: Different data sets will have different optimized parameter combinations, i.e. without data, there is no optimal parameter combination

Comment: What is the sense to pass n_estimators to RandomForestClassifier taking into account that you also pass it to GridSearchCV in param_grid?

Comment: I didn't notice that, good point. I just copy/pasted the original code when I saw that there was no call to the fit method

Comment: By the way, `'max_features'` `'auto'` is the same exact `'sqrt'` ... it's redundant to pass both !!

Comment: In the answer, the `fit()` method is called on `X` and `y`, so the `train_test_split` in the question isn't used. Should the split be dropped altogether when using `GridSearchCV`?

Comment: @JackFleeting probably best to generate a cross-validation generator and pass that to `GridSearchCV`'s `cv` parameter. At the time of writing, by default `cv` is set to 3-fold CV (this will change to 5-fold CV in v0.22)

Comment: The `GridSearchCV` sub-library was imported wrongly

Answer (score 12):

Just to add one more point to keep it clear.

The document says the following:

> best_estimator_ : estimator or dict:
>
> Estimator that was chosen by the search, i.e. estimator which gave highest score (or smallest loss if specified) on the left out data.

When the grid search is called with various params, it chooses the one with the highest score based on the given scorer func. Best estimator gives the info of the params that resulted in the highest score.

Therefore, this can only be called after fitting the data.

Comment: What becomes of `refit`?