# How to correctly compute the optimal C and gamma for my SVM?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to compute the optimal C and Gamma for my SVM. When trying to run my script I get this error:

`ValueError: Invalid parameter max_features for estimator SVC. Check the list of available parameters with`estimator.get_params().keys()`.`

I went through [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) to understand what `n_estimators` actually means so that I know what values I should fill in there. But it is not totally clear to me. Could someone tell me what this value should be so that I can run my script in order to find the optimal C and gamma?

my code:

```
if __name__=='__main__':

    fname = "/home/John/labels.csv"
    labels = pd.read_csv(fname, header=None).as_matrix()[:, 1]
    labels = map(itemgetter(1),
                 map(os.path.split,
                     map(os.path.dirname, labels))) 

    fname = "/home/John/reps.csv" 
    embeddings = pd.read_csv(fname, header=None).as_matrix()
    le = LabelEncoder().fit(labels)
    labelsNum = le.transform(labels)
    nClasses = len(le.classes_)


    svcClassifier = SVC(kernel='rbf', probability=True, C=10, gamma=10)
    #classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(svcClassifier).fit(embeddings, labelsNum)
    param_grid = { 
        'n_estimators': [200, 700],
        'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2']
    }

    CV_rfc = GridSearchCV(estimator=svcClassifier, param_grid=param_grid, cv= 5)
    CV_rfc.fit(embeddings, labelsNum)
    print CV_rfc.best_params_
```

After trying I manually found out that in my case `C=10` and `gamma=10` give the best results. I would however like to use this function to find out what the optimal values should be.

My code is insired by this post: [How to get Best Estimator on GridSearchCV (Random Forest Classifier Scikit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102973/how-to-get-best-estimator-on-gridsearchcv-random-forest-classifier-scikit)

Comment: If an answer helps you, please vote it up (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow), so that other users know which answer helped you, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SVC` class has no argument `max_features` or `n_estimators` as these are arguments of the `RandomForest` you used as a base for your code. If you want to optimize the model regarding `C` and `gamma`  you can try to use:

```
param_grid = { 
    'C': [0.1, 0.5, 1.0],
    'gamma': [0.1, 0.5, 1.0]
}
```

Furhtermore, I also recommend you to search for the optimal `kernel`, which can be `rbf`, `linear` or `poly` in the `sklearn` framework.

Edit: The values here are just arbitray and meant to illustrate the general approach. You should add many different values here, which depend on your situation. And whose range also depends on your situation.

Comment: How did you come up with those values for C and Gamma? In my case it seemed like 10 for gamma and C gave the best results so far.

Comment: @traducerad These are just arbitrary values. You should add many different values here which depend highly on your situation. My code is just an example how to search for `C` and `gamma` of a `SVC` with a `GridSearch`.

Comment: Should this list just contain all the values between which it can pick? Like eg so: [0.1, 0.2, ..., 9.8, 9.9, 10]?

Comment: In my case it is 10 that gave the best values. So it is pretty strange that it returns 0.1 and results in an incorrect classification.

Comment: @traducerad Yes. It is always a good idea to start with a list a broader values like `[0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0]` to get an idea about the the shape of the error landscape and then, choosing finer values (like in `0.1` steps). If this has answered your original question, please mark my response as the answer and vote it up, so that other users can profit from it.